# How to do neo4j parameter safe for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, neo4j, nosql

For example, the sentence is `"I'm playing football"`

The parameter needs to be `"I\'m playing football"` with single quote to neo4j architecture...

I tried `variable.html_safe` but unfortunatelly, it doesn't work.

Runtime information:

```
Neo4j database version: neo4j 3.3.1

neo4j gem version: 9.0.7

neo4j-core gem version: 8.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For references, this was answered on [an issue](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1474) in the `neo4j` repo.  Copy/pasting here:

There are a few things you could do.  The first thing that I would say is that you should never (or at least very rarely) inject data directly into a query string.  It can be:

- Buggy if you have inappropriate escaping of strings
- Slow because Neo4j can't optimize a query plan when the query string changes each time
- Unsecure if this data is coming from a user because they could produce Cypher injection attacks

Ideally `sqlParametre` should be an array so that you can do this:

```
tablo = Word.query_as(:w).where('w.ad IN {ads}').params(ads: sqlParametre)
# or as a shortcut:
tablo = Word.query_as(:w).where('w.ad IN ?', sqlParametre)
```

But since you have an `ActiveNode` model you can also work at a higher level and replace lines 89 and 91 with this:

```
kayitSayisi = Word.as(:w).where(ad: sqlParametre).pluck('SUM(w)').first
```

Note for that last line that if `sqlParametre` is an array, the `neo4j` gem automatically detects that and creates the Cypher syntax `WHERE w.ad IN {param}` instead of `WHERE w.ad = {param}`